# How to reverse engineer a section of a Drupal Page

Tags: views, theming, blocks, media

Sorry if this is a beginner or inappropriate question, but I'm trying to work on modifying a complex Drupal site and I have no idea how to find out how it's built.

At the top of the home page there's a bunch of content (specifically an image that moves and zooms like a google map) but I can't find anything about how to edit or control this area.

Where should I look? Views, Blocks, or in the Theme files? I've tried looking through all of these as best as I know but I'm hitting dead ends.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide screen shots as to what section you are trying to figure out? Is there a front-page.tpl?

Comment: You could also try to look at the source code (firebug e.g.) that most of the time reveals a bit more of what happens. And as DMAC mentioned already, the template files in your theme folder will give you more insight.

Comment: It's hard to be specific, but starting with the markup is usually the way to go. Look at the classes on the elements surrounding the area you're interested in - normally that'll tell you whether you're looking at a view, panel, rendered node, etc. Bear in mind Views can be inside blocks, and each can be themed independently, and a block could easily contain a node containing a view containing other nodes, and so on, so it may get murky. Something like the [Theme Developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module can help to identify templates, but it's known to be a bit buggy

Comment: Some themes hide their magic under the appearance settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could use more specifics, but I think I understand what you are experiencing.

I've been there. If you cannot find it anywhere, a good bet is that it is part of the theme tpl pages. If you want to confirm this, you should go to the sites/all/themes/whatever-theme-you-are-using and search for files ending in .tpl.php, which are the files that control the theme you are currently using.

Frequently, any special effect or non-drupal configurable behaviour is likely inserted directly into these files. If your intention is to re-use whatever you are seeing at the top of the page, look for js (javascript) files: it is likely that dynamic pages are using some library, and that by googling the js filenames you can find a reference that might be useful.

At least, it has worked for me.